# external table with partitions in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a bunch of tsv files in HDFS in a directory structure that follows the partition convention where an `event_dt` is the partition.

```
some_path/event_dt=2017-04-30
some_path/event_dt=2017-05-01
```

and so on.

The issue is that event_dt is also one of the columns. The second one in particular.  But I cannot specify so since `event_dt` cannot appear in the table schema and in the `PARTITIONED BY` statement. That triggers:

```
 Column repeated in partitioning columns
```

Is there a way around this other than using different names. It is, after all, the same information.

Comment: Let it dynamic partition on the basis of `event_dt` whenever you load the data?

Comment: Any reason not to rename the non-partition column?

Comment: having two names that refer to the exact same thing feels a bit strange I guess

Answer (score -1):

3 options if you dont want to rename the column.

1. If your event_dt is the last column in your csv, you create the table excluding this column.
2. During the ingestion process exclude this information of your data, transforming the data from one place to another where the target table is partitioned by even_dt (not the most efficient way)
3. create a view on top of your table excluding one of the columns, anyway the original table will need the rename .